# cannont have bluetooth in arch linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, archlinux

tengo arch linux desde hace 4 meses en una laptop que tiene bluetooth incluido y todo esta funcionando perfectamente, pero trate te installer arch linux en una computadora que no tiene bluetooth. asi que compre un adaptador usb para el bluetooth.
y estoy teniendo estos problemas cuando intento conectar al internet
aqui anexo el intento de conectarme al bluetooth y la informacion correspondiende

```
[bluetooth]# power on
Changing power on succeeded
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# show
Controller 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10 (public)
        Name: BlueZ 5.61
        Alias: BlueZ 5.61
        Class: 0x0000010c
        Powered: yes
        Discoverable: no
        DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
        Pairable: no
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Handsfree Audio Gateway   (0000111f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        UUID: Device Information        (0000180a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34
        Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d053D
        Discovering: no
        Roles: central
        Roles: peripheral
Advertising Features:
        ActiveInstances: 0x00 (0)
        SupportedInstances: 0x05 (5)
        SupportedIncludes: tx-power
        SupportedIncludes: appearance
        SupportedIncludes: local-name
Failed to start discovery: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
```

como pueden ver el dispositivo bluetooth esta prendido de pero no regresa ningun output como respuesta, en la informacion correspondiente se puede ver que discoverable y pairable estan negativos. asi que intente

```
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Failed to set pairable on: org.bluez.Error.Busy
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Failed to set discoverable on: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply
```

pero como pueden ver falla

```
sudo btmgmt
[hci0]# info
hci0:   Primary controller
        addr 00:1A:7D:DA:71:10 version 9 manufacturer 10 class 0x00010c
        supported settings: powered connectable fast-connectable discoverable bondable link-security ssp br/edr le advertising secure-conn debug-keys privacy static-addr phy-configuration
        current settings: powered ssp br/edr le secure-conn
        name BlueZ 5.61
        short name
[hci0]# connectable on
Set Connectable for hci0 failed with status 0x03 (Failed)
```

cualquier ayuda es bienvenida

Comment: Hello, we are in Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Aparte del idioma, este sitio es para preguntas de programación, no para configuración del SO.